# How to create a wrapper script which starts java application handling its dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a thin jar stored in Nexus (or Maven Central).
It can be started as `java -cp "$DEPENDENCIES:$JAR_ITSELF" "$MAIN_CLASS"`.

How can I automatically create a script which would download the jar and all of its dependencies from the Nexus and start the application?

Comment: All dependencies should be packaged in the same jar. Just one jar should be started which will references all what you need.

Comment: you can contain the dependencies as resources and extract them at run-time if they don't exist.  So it runs if they have already been extracted, or it extracts and then runs if they do not.  You could also run a check against version numbers and download/overwrite files if they don't match stored values.  (Tricky to keep track of multiples, but sounds like you're looking to auto-patch?)